# Struts2 There is no Action mapped

Tags: input, struts2, action

i'm using `Struts 2.3.15.2`. I wrote my actions:

```
<action name="ricerca" class="com.emaborsa.doctracing.web.action.ricerca.RicercaUtentiAction" method="ricerca">
    <result name="input" type="tiles">utente.ricerca.def</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">utente.elenco.def</result>
</action>
```

if in the url i call `localhost:8080/myProject/ricerca.action` it works. If i call `localhost:8080/myProject/ricerca!input.action` it throws my:

```
2013-10-16 23:49:50,602 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] [http-bio-8080-exec-8] Exception occurred during processing request: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/utente] and action name [ricerca!input] associated with context path [/myProject].
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/utente] and action name [ricerca!input] associated with context path [/myProject]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't understand if it is a problem of some setting or something else. On an older version of struts it works but i had to upgrade due to incompatiblity problems with tiles.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to do that? Are you trying to reach the page? If so, you have to access via .../ricerca.action, then return "input" in the execute() function of RicercaUtentiAction class

Comment: Because it's a feature of struts2. Otherwise i had to define a further action. If i'm not wrong it is explained also in "Struts in action" book.

Comment: You need to enable DMI.

Comment: ...isn't it enabled by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set `struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation = TRUE` in your `struts.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check namespace in your struts-config.xml

```
<package name="example" namespace="/example">
```

Please refer this book, It will be given a guide to you.

[Struts2 in action](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://my-pproj-j.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/files/Struts%25202%2520in%2520Action_166.pdf&ei=tW1fUpC1KcuQhQfF4IDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEy8wJ8x9el8_ivSZjqNpzFCjZViQ&sig2=mUY0WVbcwPzi7E9ujfaxcA&bvm=bv.54176721,d.ZG4)

Comment: The namespace should not be the problem, since the to action i wrote have the same but only one action works. I think the problem is that the framework doesn't recognize the !input